# notepad++ regex search and add at end of line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

i have multiple files that i must edit, example:

> Process.Start process 1234154
>
> Start test
>
> Process.Start
>
> Process.Start process example

now i need to do search and in every line where is "Process.Start process" at end of that line i need to add "shell=True" word

any fast way to do that?
my search is (Process.Start process) but Im not sure how to add text on end of that specific line

Comment: Did you try anything? It sounds easy, just match a line with `.*Process\.Start process.*` and replace with the 0th backreference adding the text you need.

Comment: **Find:** `^(Process\.Start process .+)`

**Replace With:** `$1 shell=True`

Comment: works like charm, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl-H, select the regular expression match, then search for `(Process\.Start process.*)` and replace it with `\1 shell=True`.

`\1` means "whatever is matched by the first parentheses in the search string", so in this case it would be the whole line. The dot between "Process" and "Start" must be escaped with a backslash or it will be treated as a special character meaning "anything". `.*` means: any number of any characters, so that it doesn't matter what comes after "Process.Start process", it will always match.

Comment: You can do it wihtout enclosing the whole pattern with a capturing group.

Comment: @stribizhev This is the most obvious way of doing it (at least for me). Anyway, I'd be interested in seeing how you'd do it. I've seen your comment, but I don't follow you on the 0th backreference.

Comment: Just remove `(` and `)` from your pattern and use `$0 shell=True` as replacement. The whole match can be referenced to with a zeroth backreference. In Perl, it is not encouraged since it hampers the whole code execution, but Notepad++ uses Boost regex library that should work well with the `$0` backreference.

Comment: @stribizhev Ah, now I see. I had tried with `\0`, instead it's `$0`. Nice! If you post it as an answer you'll get an upvote! :-)